# EPSG CRS Error Trap

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, pyproj

I'm using pyproj and I'd like to run an error trap on the EPSG CRS code. Specifically, if the user enters a EPSG CRS code that is not in the proj database, it would provide a Boolean flag I can check before proceeding. I currently get this message if I enter a bad EPSG CRS:

```
File "pyproj\_crs.pyx", line 2338, in pyproj._crs._CRS.__init__
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:000: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from pyproj import CRS
from pyproj.exceptions import CRSError

try:
    CRS.from_epsg(...)
    valid = True
except CRSError:
    valid = False
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you @snowman2